# JPA/Hibernate, Query timestamp column ignores time part of criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, date, jpa

I'm using JPA/Hibernate combination to store entities to an oracle database.

The table contains a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column to store a date value with time and milliseconds.

Storing and loading the entity works as intended. The "time" part of the java.util.Date field in the entity is processed correctly.

But when I query the table with a native query and `where time < :startTime` condition the startTime only contains date '30-Jul-14'. The "time" part is truncated.

Hibernates query look like:

```
select documentta0_.id as id1_14_, documentta0_.id_document as id5_14_, documentta0_.host as host2_14_, documentta0_.task as task3_14_, documentta0_.time as time4_14_ 
from document_task documentta0_ 
where documentta0_.task='preview' 
and documentta0_.host='my.host.uk' 
and documentta0_.time>'30-Jul-14' 
order by documentta0_.time ASC
```

The orm.xml File contains the following column definition:

```
<basic name="time" optional="false">
     <column name="time"/>
     <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
</basic>
```

How to query with date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is just a matter of formatting. In case that you are using something like p6spy, try uncommenting and setting the property to

```
databaseDialectDateFormat=dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

Comment: yes my fault, I changed the setting and the output is now correct